# Is reading newspaper at work acceptable?

Tags: professionalism

I work in fashion industry. There is no policy about reading newspaper. I have a habit of reading newspaper every morning, and unfortunately, at work. I read for about an hour. Should I change my habit? I feel great & have more energy to work after reading the news stuffs

Comment: Are you on the clock or is this on your break?  I am hard pressed to believe that your employer would want to pay you to spend an hour to read the newspaper rather than whatever you were hired to do.  If you have an hour break, no one probably cares.

Comment: yeah. they don't. I ask because I see other employees reading newspaper and surfing. btw, anyone know why the comments under the questions are sometimes deleted. I got mine deleted once in a while. I dont think I say anything rude?

Comment: Comments are intended to be deleted, they're designed to seek clarifications to questions and answers that can be edited in to the question.  If you know your employer doesn't want you to spend an hour on the clock reading the newspaper, I don't see how there is a viable question here.  Read the newspaper on your own time at home or on your commute in, show up energized to work, and work during the hours you are on the clock.

Comment: "I read for about an hour" - can you possibly read for a shorter amount of time, or spread it out? e.g. read a few minutes in the morning, and then the rest during your lunch. The newspaper reading is probably not a problem, but spending one hour in the morning is when you're supposed to be working.

Answer (score 8):

I have seen workplaces where this would be acceptable. Mainly because there is no urgency about work and not a lot to do sometimes. I've also seen government offices where half the staff play solitaire or facebook all day.

But in general, no, this isn't an acceptable practice, and it's a bad habit to have. If you change workplaces when/if this one falls to bits you then have a bad habit you need to break. Best to train yourself out of it now.

So even if it is acceptable in this particular workplace, I'd still advise against it.

Answer (score 4):

> I read for about an hour. Should I change my habit? I feel great &
>   have more energy to work after reading the news stuffs.

Ask your boss if it's okay for you to spend an hour reading instead of doing work, so that you will feel great and have more energy afterwards.

That's the only way you'll know if it is acceptable or not.

And if you don't think you should ask your boss, then that tells me you already know the acceptability of your actions.

Comment: +1 IMO, this is the best answer: " if you don't think you should ask your boss, then that tells me you already know the acceptability of your actions"

Answer (score 3):

How about you bring in your toys to work and play at your desk?

How about you just take a nap?  Wouldn't that up your energy level?

Do you think everyone likes to be at work?  That is why they call it work.

How about when you get fired from this job you hire a lawyer to sue.  Lawyer charges you $500 an hour.  After talking with him for 20 mins, he excuses himself.  Comes back an hour later, had to take a crap.  Well it was a $500 crap that you paid for.

Since your employer probably understands that you do this daily you are literally taking a $500 a month crap at your desk.

So is it OK?   No.  Will it get you fired?  Probably.

The fact is whether right or wrong, surfing the net while answering emails or talking on the phone is a waste of company time too, but having a newspaper spread eagle in the middle of the office for an hour a day... well that just says I know I am not working and I don't give a shit.

Comment: I'd change the "probably" to "possibly". Your boss is probably more interested to know whether you get the job done. If you're behind schedule, they might see this habit as a hindrance... and yes, that might lead to you being fired.

Comment: @blankip could you tone it down a notch there is no need to attack the op.

Comment: The paragraph about the lawyer taking a crap is where it goes too far. A little bit of sarcasm but not overboard.

Answer (score 3):

### No, it's not acceptable.

The only place where this would be acceptable is **if news and news coverage is an essential part of your business and/or role**.

For example if you are working in the PR department, as press relations officer, spokesman or something related, then staying on top of the day-to-day news is an fundamental part of your responsibility.

If you're reading news to relax, up your energy level, for entertainment, etc. this is your personal business which you should do in your private time.

Answer (score 2):

There are only 2 occasions I can think of where reading the newspaper at work would be acceptable:

1. During your lunch hour/break, which for many people is unpaid. During this time you can relax by reading the paper, playing chess, going for a walk etc. That is doing non-work activities
2. If reading the paper is part of your job, such as if you are asked to add contemporary reports and trends to a research article. But you should only be looking at the content that is useful for you job, not solving the crossword

Comment: OP mentioned that there is no policy about reading the paper. Indicating that it is not one of his Tasks to search the papers.